# unable to paste the formula

Tags: excel, powershell, excel-formula, command, vba

Below  is the powershell command  which is used to copy the data from one excel to multiple excel file in  destination directory.

But my question is, the formulas are not pasting as formula instead it is pasting as value.

can any one alter this script  to paste the formula?

```
    $sourceFile = "c:\tmp\source.xlsx"
$destinationDirectory = "c:\tmp"
$sheetName = "Sheet1"
$rangeToCopyStart = "B19"
$rangeToCopyEnd = "B49"

#----------------------------------------------
# Open Excel source file
#----------------------------------------------

$excelApplication = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application                        
$excelWorkbook = $excelApplication.Workbooks.Open($sourceFile, 2, $True)
$excelWorksheet = $excelWorkbook.Worksheets.Item($sheetName)            

#----------------------------------------------
# Copy the cell value 
#----------------------------------------------

"Value to copy:" + $excelWorksheet.Range($rangeToCopyStart, $rangeToCopyEnd).Value2;
"From:" + $sourceFile;
$excelWorksheet.Range($rangeToCopyStart, $rangeToCopyEnd).Copy() | out-null;
$excelWorkbook.Close();                                                

#----------------------------------------------
# Get all Excel files from destination directory 
#----------------------------------------------

$Files = Get-ChildItem $destinationDirectory -Filter *.xlsx

Foreach ($Item in $Files) {

    $destinationFile = $Item.FullName

    #----------------------------------------------
    # Skip the source file if it's in the same directory 
    #----------------------------------------------


    If ($sourceFile.ToLower() -eq $destinationFile.ToLower())  { continue; }  

    $destinationWorkbook = $excelApplication.Workbooks.Open($destinationFile, 2, $False)       
    $destinationWorkSheet = $destinationWorkbook.Worksheets.Item($sheetName)                 

    #----------------------------------------------
    # Paste the value into the destination file
    #----------------------------------------------

    $destinationWorkSheet.Paste($destinationWorkSheet.Range($rangeToCopyStart, $rangeToCopyEnd)); 
    $destinationWorkbook.Close($True);  #save changes and close

    "Copied to: " + $destinationFile;
}


#----------------------------------------------
# Quit Excel and release the object
#----------------------------------------------

$excelApplication.Quit();
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($excelApplication) | out-null;
```

Comment: You have to use PasteSpecial

Comment: $destinationWorkSheet.PasteSpecial($destinationWorkSheet.Range($rangeToCopyStart, $rangeToCopyEnd)); 
    $destinationWorkbook.Close($True);  #save changes and close                     even after i change to pastespecial also it does not paste the formula. can any one pls change  the script and share me

Comment: @mani, I guess you need to have your source workbook open, when you are pasting the copied cells. So, move `$excelWorkbook.Close(); ` after your `For Each` and give it a try.

Comment: @Arul  i dont find any difficulties in copy and paste between source to destination .. but my concern is to paste the formula as formula .. not as value.

Comment: @mani, When you paste after closing the source workbook, the copied cells would be pasted as values. Only when you have the source workbook open, the copied cells will be pasted as in source. i.e. formula in your case.

Comment: @Arul.. thanks. it works..  when i  deleted this $excelWorkbook.Close() from the script and kept open the source file ... is there any workarround that i can run without opening  source file..

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***Range.PasteSpecial*** instead of ***Range.Copy*** method.

```
$xl=new-object -com excel.application
$wb1=$xl.workbooks.open($Source_Workbook, $null, $true)
$wb2=$xl.workbooks.open($Destination_Workbook)
$target=$wb2.Worksheets.Item($Target_Worksheet).Range('B2','B2')
$wb1.Worksheets.Item($Source_Worksheet).Range('a2','a2').copy()
$wb2.Worksheets.Item($Target_Worksheet).Activate()
$target.PasteSpecial(-4163)
```

Hope it helps